# Does MAXIMO support SAML authentication

Tags: maximo

We want to allow our users to authenticate on MAXIMO via our external F5 BIG-IP firewall. Is it possible to setup MAXIMO to integrate with this appliance and use authentication token issues by this firewall. BTW, we are deploying MAXIMO on AWS cloud and would need to tunnel these tokens back to the on-premise firewall appliance.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Maximo does support Security Assertion Markup Language (SAML):

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSLKT6_7.6.0.8/com.ibm.mbs.doc/securgroup/c_saml_security.html